# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'userprofile'

Tags: python, attributes, nonetype

I keep getting this error and I'm kind of stuck. I know that it has something to do with the last bit of code but, other than that, I'm mostly confused and I'm not really sure how to go about fixing it/implementing fixes.

> The section that calls Panel (part of a visual options menu):

```
    self.AutojoinMemosPanel = GUI.Options.Panels.AutojoinMemos.Panel(self.config,self)
    self.pages.addWidget(self.AutojoinMemosPanel)
```

> Panel:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MemoEntryItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
def __init__(self,MemoName):
    QtGui.QListWidgetItem.__init__(self,MemoName)
    self.MemoName = MemoName

class Panel(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self,Config,userprofile):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.Config = Config

    self.AutoIdentifyCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox("Automatically identify with nickserv")
    self.PasswordLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Password:")
    self.PasswordEntry = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.PasswordEntry.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)

    self.TitleLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Memos to join on startup:")
    self.MemosList = QtGui.QListWidget()
    self.MemoNameEntry = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.RemoveButton = QtGui.QPushButton("REMOVE")
    self.AddButton = QtGui.QPushButton("ADD")

    Layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    Layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    Layout.addWidget(self.AutoIdentifyCheck)
    NickservPasswordLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    NickservPasswordLayout.addWidget(self.PasswordLabel)
    NickservPasswordLayout.addWidget(self.PasswordEntry)
    Layout.addLayout(NickservPasswordLayout)
    Layout.addWidget(self.TitleLabel)
    Layout.addWidget(self.MemosList)
    Layout.addWidget(self.MemoNameEntry)
    AddRemoveButtonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    AddRemoveButtonLayout.addWidget(self.RemoveButton)
    AddRemoveButtonLayout.addWidget(self.AddButton)
    Layout.addLayout(AddRemoveButtonLayout)

    self.connect(self.RemoveButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self,QtCore.SLOT("RemoveSelectedMemo()"))
    self.connect(self.AddButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self,QtCore.SLOT("AddMemoFromTextEntry()"))

    if self.Config.userprofile.userprofile.get("AutoIdentify",False):
        self.AutoIdentifyCheck.setChecked(True)

    self.PasswordEntry.setText(self.Config.userprofile.userprofile.get("NickservPassword",""))

    for MemoName in self.Config.config.get("AutojoinMemos",[]):
        self.AddMemoEntry(MemoName)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def RemoveSelectedMemo(self):
    self.MemosList.takeItem(self.MemosList.currentRow())

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def AddMemoFromTextEntry(self):
    MemoName = str(self.MemoNameEntry.text()).strip()
    if (MemoName != ""):
        self.AddMemoEntry(MemoName)
        self.MemoNameEntry.setText("")

def AddMemoEntry(self,MemoName):
    self.MemosList.addItem(MemoEntryItem(MemoName))

def SaveOptions(self):
    MemosListed = []

    for MemoIndex in range(self.MemosList.count()):
        MemoItem = self.MemosList.item(MemoIndex)
        MemosListed.append(MemoItem.MemoName)

    self.Config.set("AutojoinMemos",MemosListed)

    self.Config.userprofile.userprofile["AutoIdentify"] = self.AutoIdentifyCheck.isChecked()
    self.Config.userprofile.userprofile["NickservPassword"] = str(self.PasswordEntry.text())
    self.Config.userprofile.save()
```

Any help?

Comment: May want to add language tag to question (e.g. [python]).

Comment: looks like `self.Config.userprofile` is `None`

Comment: @karthikr Or `self.Config`.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the Panel class?

Comment: It can't be `self.Config.userprofile` because it would throw an `AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'userprofile'` error before trying to access the second `userprofile` (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

At first thought, one of two things could be happening here. Upon deeper inspection, there's only one.

Let's assume, since you didn't state explicitly, that the problematic line is:

```
if self.Config.userprofile.userprofile.get("AutoIdentify",False):
```

Then when you get the error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'userprofile'`

means that you are trying to access an attribute which does not exist (which is the meaning behind `has no attribute 'userprofile'`), and that *the object* you're checking an attribute for doesn't exist, since the type of an object that doesn't exist is `NoneType` (which is the meaning behind `'NoneType' object`).

So to debug, you want to look for possibilities where the object accessing `userprofile` could be `None` (i.e. not assigned or null). This is possible at

```
self.Config.userprofile #1
```

and

```
self.Config.userprofile.userprofile #2
```

In #1, if the value of Config is `None`, then `self.Config.userprofile` will throw that AttributeError because `Config` is a `NoneType` object, and thus has no attributes--let alone a `userprofile` attribute.

In #2 if the value of `userprofile` *of* `self.Congig` is `None`, then `self.Config.userprofile.userprofile` will throw that AttributeError because `userprofile` is a `NoneType` object and therefore has no attributes either.

However, you can eliminate one of these two options.

Think about it, #2 could never throw this error because if the attribute `userprofile` of the object `self.Config` was `None` (as expained above), then you would first throw a different error:

```
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'userprofile'
```

If `Config` object *did* have an attribute `userprofile` then you would get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'userprofile' object has no attribute 'userprofile'
```

Therefore, `Config` must be `None`, which means you're not passing `Config` in with a value to `__init__`.

Hope this helps to fix your issue and to debug better on your own!

Comment: This is a fantastic walkthru

Comment: How would I go about passing Config with a value to __init__ ?

Comment: How are you currently setting the value of Config?

Comment: `__init__` is the constructor of your Panel object, so you would pass in the config when you create the Panel object. I'm not sure where you create the Panel object, but you would do (for whatever the config is, as variable c): `p=Panel(c)` This will pass c as `Config` in the `__init__` method.